# Binomial Theorem and Pascal's Triangle

Tags: binomial-theorem

What is the sum of all of the coefficients $(4x-3)^{10}$? 
The answer is $1$ but I need a faster way of doing this.  Right now I just expanded it all using Pascal's triangle and $n$ choose $k$.  I took this down to $(4x-3)^{4}$ and got $1$ as well.  I then did $(4x-2)^{4}$ and got $16$.  So is there a formula for finding the sum of coefficients for $(ax-by)^{n}$ just as $(a-b)^n$?

What about when it is $(ax+by)^{n}$?

Comment: When you edited my post did you do \choose or did you use another way? It looked as if by italicizing my n and k and putting "choose" in between made it work...

Answer (score 3):

The sum of all the coefficients should equal to $p(1) = (4\cdot 1 - 3)^{10} = 1$  with $p(x) = (4x - 3)^{10}$

Comment: Why put 1 in for x?  My instructor once showed this but I did not follow.

Comment: Write any polynomial and notice what its value is for $ \ x = 1 \ $ .

Comment: Consider how 1 doesn't affect the products at each term as 1 raised to any positive integer power is still 1.

Comment: For a polynomial $P$, $P(1)$ is the sum of all the coefficients

Answer (score 1):

There is, I haven't really mastered the art of LaTeX, so I won't be able to write the exact solution, but, the idea is as follows:

Use Binomial Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Supplement it with a "Sum from k to n" for the coefficient. Simplify the equation.

If you do that, you're going to notice that this solves both the original question, and the question of $(ax+by)^c$

Comment: Oh, and heads up, your question is a really popular one for exams. Usually one of those superhard questions noone answers that is required for top grade.